# Is there a way to delete something that has been shelved?

Tags: tortoise-svn

TortoiseSVN has the option to shelve/unshelve changes.  I couldn't find a way to delete something that was shelved.  The workaround I use is unshelve on a clean working copy and then reverting.

Comment: Deleting shelves is provided in TortoiseSVN as of version 1.14.*. You open the unshelve dialog, select the shelf and hit the *Delete* button. Of course, earlier shelves may not be accessible by this (I'd guess they are removed automatically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be an answer, but I think you will have to wait for TortoiseSVN
to reach SVN version 1.11, and until then to continue to use your workaround.

New in version 1.11 is the command `x-shelf-drop` (shelf-drop) to delete a shelf,
as listed in the Apache article of
[Shelving in Svn-trunk](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SVN/Shelving+in+Svn-trunk).

Current [TortoiseSVN version](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) is described as:

> The current version 1.10.1 is linked against the Subversion library 1.10.2.

Comment: This is still not resolved in TortoiseSVN 1.12, which is linked to SVN 1.12.0.  The answer by @Grilse is the only way to delete shelves at the moment.

Answer (score 9):

TortoiseSVN's Unshelve does not delete (drop) the shelf for me, regardless of whether the unshelving yields conflicts or not. (I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.11.1, Build 28492)

Workaround: delete/drop the shelf using SVN directly, rather than via TortoiseSVN. In a console:

```
$ svn help x-shelf-drop
x-shelf-drop: Delete a shelf.
usage: x-shelf-drop SHELF [PATH ...]

  Delete the shelves named SHELF from the working copies containing PATH
  (default PATH is '.')

…

$ svn x-shelf-drop "Name of shelf"
deleted 'Name of shelf'
```

Docs: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SVN/Shelving+in+Svn-trunk

Comment: And to use the command line when you have TortoiseSVN, re-run the setup and add "command line client tools"

Comment: This is still the case in TortoiseSVN 1.12.0.